# Enable OS X Mail editing toolbar

Tags: macos, mail.app

Some time ago somebody helped me to know how to display the OS X Mail **message editing** toolbar. Please note, this is not the main Mail toolbar, but appears on the message window. I did not record the steps, but I recall it is very simple. I would like to know how to enable that on a new computer.

Please look at the screen shot to see the toolbar that I am talking about. It is easy to find a ton of information about customizing the main toolbar. But I cannot find anything about enabling this one.

The toolbar in question is the bottom-most of the three toolbars shown, and has "Helvetica" visible in the first drop down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just clic on the **A** on the top right of your message window.

[image]

Comment: How could I miss that! And twice! Doh!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered ;)